# Linq IN in C# error

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do this:

```
myList = (from c in ipE.Cars
          where (someListOfIntegers.Contains(idCar) && c.name == someName)
          select c).ToList();
```

I'm getting the eror LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I tried with ANY, it still doesn't work. I got the error Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file?

Comment: @Sjoerd the "cannot be translated into a store expression" is a runtime/provider error, not a compiler error; a `using` directive is not the issue

Comment: @Marc Gravell read question again, user mentioned Linq to Entities

Comment: where is someListOfIntegers? Because it's Linq to Entities, this LINQ query will be translated to SQL. But SQL knows nothing about someListOfIntegers...

Comment: someListOfIntegers and idCar seems not to come form your db objects? Or did you mean `c.idCar`?

Comment: Which wersion of Entity Framework are you using? I cannot do quick check right now, but from what I remember using list of integers as 'parameter' in Linq 2 Entities worked fine in EF4.0.

Comment: @MattDavey that doesn't stop other providers (LINQ-to-SQL, for example) from handling this situation just fine. Simply, the EF translation is a bit ... lacking.

Comment: @Pako The version is 2.0

Comment: @Jan They don't come from my db objects.

Comment: Then i don't understand, why you include that into your EF query?

Comment: As Jan notes; if that test has **nothing whatsoever** to do with the DB (neither the list nor the value is in the DB) - DON'T DO IT IN THE QUERY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be suggesting (comments) that `idCar` does not relate to any entities - in which case, *don't do that in the query*:

```
List<Car> list;
if(someListOfIntegers.Contains(idCar)) {
    myList = (from c in ipE.Cars
              where c.name == someName
              select c).ToList();
} else {
    myList = new List<Car>(); // no need to touch the DB
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you cant't use local collections in an EF query. You can work around it, by using the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and translate the `Contains` operation manually in a sequence of `OR`s:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Car>();
foreach (int id in someListOfIntegers)
{
   int temp = id;
   predicate = predicate.Or (car => car.idCar == id);
}


myList = (from c in ipE.Cars
    where predicate && c.name == someName)
    select c).ToList();
```

Sidenote: I assume, that you have a typo in your question, because neither `someListOfIntegers` nor `idCar` are properties of your EF model you query. So i guess you want to query for `Car.idCar?`.

Otherwise you just could refactor the `Contains` completely out of the EF query.

Answer (score -1):

Seen the same myself: L2E uses a small set of commands - and there isn't a "Contains(Int32)" command.

If your lists are fairly small, then try adding ".AsEnumerable()", which will execute the T-SQL select statements and leave you with POCO objects which CAN use Contains.
e.g.

```
myList = (from c in ipE.Cars.AsEnumerable
       where (someListOfIntegers.AsEnumerable().Contains(idCar) 
       && c.name == someName)           
       select c)
       .ToList();
```

Not sure if you need both AsEnumerables...try it out!

Comment: "and there isn't a "Contains(Int32)" command in T-SQL" in this context, yes there is - it would be `table.Column in (@the,@list,@of,@integers)` - which other providers do just fine at. Adding `AsEnumerable()` here is **really** dangerous - you are now pulling the entire table to the caller.

Comment: I get an error too...I also wrote "If your lists are fairly small" to make sure of the point that it DOES pull all the table, but this may be OK.